# problem with ie6 and dynamically-generated panels

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, dynamically-generated

I'm experiencing problem with ie6 and dynamically generated components. have a static panel (main one) with a scroll bar and I'm dynamically placing other (smaller) panels into the main. these smaller ones contain other components... close to the point, here are the  screenshots that exactly give the point of my problem with ie6.

http://www.turboimagehost.com/p/7333211/ie6.JPG.html

thats how it looks in ie6.
on the other hand heres how page looks in ff. thats exactly the way it was planned to be (same look with other major browsers)

http://www.turboimagehost.com/p/7333209/ff3a.JPG.html
http://www.turboimagehost.com/p/7333210/ff3b.JPG.html

Comment: Suggest you to provide bare-minimum html/js that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: no html/js... source is c#. anyways, heres simplified version of it (hope it make things clear)



Panel video_panel = new Panel[s_count]
int i = 0;
//here comes loop
foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
{
jpg_panel[i] = new Panel();
main_panel.Controls.Add(video_panel[i]);
video_panel[i].ID = "j_" + i.ToString();
video_panel[i].Style["position"] = "absolute";
video_panel[i].Style["top"] = Convert.ToString(i*300) + "px";
video_panel[i].Style["left"] = "0px";
video_panel[i].Width = 240;
video_panel[i].Height = 300;
i++;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you are using absolute positioning for child div, you haven't specify the style for your parent. But most probably, you are encountering well-known IE6 bug - see [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/) for problem and solution - in short, you need to **use relative position for your container(parent) div/panel**.

On the other hand, for the suggested layout, you need not use absolute positioning. You can use margins to control the layout - see [a sample fiddle out here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fabe/9/).

Comment: thanks for the article bout IE6  bug.
relative positioning saved the day.